# PDF Download Only

Tags: macos, browser, pdf, download, adobe-acrobat

On a Mac how do you download a PDF and not automatically open it in Acrobat?

Comment: Depends on what browser you're using...

Answer (score 1):

For Safari, type this in Terminal :

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari WebKitOmitPDFSupport -bool YES
```

Comment: Does that actually do anything to Adobe's plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the website and then `Right-click` the link and do `Save Linked File As...`